# Calling a function inside a twig for loop

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can i call a function inside a twig for loop.
I have a array output of the database and i call it inside twig like this:

```
<tbody>
{% for O in Orders %}
<tr>
<td>{{ O.DomainName~'.'~O.Extension }}</td>
<td>{{ O.Package }}</td>
<td>{{ O.StoreDate }}</td>
<td>{{ O.ExecuteDate }}</td>
<td>{{ O.Email }}</td>
<td>{{ O.UserIP }}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

`UserIP` wil return the IP Address.
What i want to accomplish is to call the function below for every user and add that to the table.

```
    public function ip_country($userIP)
{
    $ip = $userIP;
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}"));

    return $details->country_code; // -> "US"
}
```

Now i know that i can not call a function directly from twig.
Do i need to add that as a twig extension with `twig_simplefunction`?

Comment: Why call the function in the view and not in the controller and simply return all the data you need.

Comment: i've tried that with array_push to add the country to the array but i dont think that it was the right way to do that. And i am already rendering the template with Orders and if i add anotherone i will get a for inside a for loop

Comment: For inside a for in not anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Yep.  Make yourself a filter extension. Then your twig would be {{ UserIP | ip_country }}

Comment: in my other framework i could do something like this [{{ 'ip_country'|php(o.UserIP) }}] inside .tpl is there something like that in twig?

Comment: Yes, function and filter : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Nope.  You really can't put php inside of a twig template.  Embrace the twig way of doing things or use a different template system.  Once you have worked through the process then adding an extension is straight forward.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I think that the filter extension is the right thing to do here (Y)

Comment: Technically (though I think this is massively against MVC and the way Symfony does things), you could add that function to the User Entity, rename it to getIpCountry() and then call it from the Twig directly using O.user.ipCountry (assuming the User is linked within the Order).

Would also suggest a Twig filter/function instead, obviously. Just saying, it could be done.

Comment: @AJCerqueti - so view helpers violate MVC and Symfony?  Interesting.  Makes you wonder why twig has so many built in functions.

Comment: @Cerad Again, my opinion, but I'd say this function is business logic, rather than pure data, so it shouldn't be in the entity, it should be in a service that a Twig filter/function accesses. My example was more to say it could be done without a Twig extension, but I wouldn't recommend doing it that way :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a twig extension and wrap your code inside it. Your code will get more clean and won't pollute the views and controllers.

First create a filter

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;
class MyIpExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
  public function getFilters()
  {
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('ipcountry', array($this, 'country')),
    );
  }

  public function ip_country($userIP) {
    $ip = $userIP;
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}"));

    return $details->country_code; // -> "US"
 }


  public function getName()
  {
     return 'app_extension';
  }
}
```

And then register as a symfony container service

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
   app.twig_extension:
      class: AppBundle\Twig\MyIpExtension
      public: false
      tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

And then use the extension in your twig views

```
{{ O.UserIP | ipcountry }}
```

Pay close attention on class names and namespaces. Make the necessary adaptation to your environment.